ARM SBC with Type-C with DP RX 1.4A for real-time video streaming
Is there even a single ARM SBC \ SoC that can be programmed and then, being connected via Type-C (like USB Hubs do) to a host, present itself like Headphones, Mic, LAN card, and the hardest thing - an ordinary USB Monitor (Screen)? Yes, it should work in Alt mode as a peripheral to emulate a monitor.
I struggle to find one and wonder why this is such an unpopular need.
Yes, there's the "HDMI to CSI-2 module" for RPI and plenty of everyday "USB TO HDMI" dongles that can possibly work with Orange Pi 5 Plus, which has native HDMI input. But.
To create an efficient device with minimal delay for capturing, encoding, and transmitting, the device should have a decent GPU capable of native h.264 encoding on hardware (VPU\GPU) and USB Type-C that can work in device mode with supports of DP RX 1.4A or similar.
Probably, this problem is just a good task for a hardware designer and manufacturer (which will cost not less than 1-2 hundreds of thousands in the end, right?).
I just wanted to ensure I have explored all the existing options.
